# Creating a new object with same keys and values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to create a new Object and inside of it insert certain values from an 'old' Object, I've trying to do this for a while now but everytime I end up in the same spot.

```
[
{ initials: "HLC", name: "HAPAG", color: "#FF8040" }
​
{ initials: "HMM", name: "HYUNDAI", color: "#C10D11" }
​
{ initials: "MSC", name: "MSC", color: "#F5BA07" }
​
{ initials: "ONE", name: "ONE", color: "#A80F89" }
]
```

This would be Object that i'm getting from an API (it's inside of an array)  and i need to create a new object with only specific values, like this:

```
const newObj = {
initials: "HLC",
initials: "HMM",
initials: "MSC",
initials: "ONE",
}
```

Somehow I always end up with a `newObj = {initials: "ONE"}` and I think it's because I'm using an loop to do it.
I would need to do with the other two keys the same, but if I understand how to do it with one key I'll be good.

Comment: you can't have an object with same keys, you could make `initials` an array with values

Comment: An object cannot have duplicate keys. You are using the key `initials` four times. It is not really possible to construct an object like what you have written in js.

Comment: Oh damn, i didn't know about that, so the best use would be for me to do `newObj = [{initials: "HLC"},{...},{...}] `?

Answer (score 2):

You can map [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) fields as [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) to a new object.

```js
const original = [
  { initials: "HLC" , name: "HAPAG"   , color: "#FF8040" },
  { initials: "HMM" , name: "HYUNDAI" , color: "#C10D11" },
  { initials: "MSC" , name: "MSC"     , color: "#F5BA07" },
  { initials: "ONE" , name: "ONE"     , color: "#A80F89" }
];

const modified = original.map(({ initials }) => ({ initials }));

console.log(modified);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want all the initials, you can map them similarly:

```js
const original = [
  { initials: "HLC" , name: "HAPAG"   , color: "#FF8040" },
  { initials: "HMM" , name: "HYUNDAI" , color: "#C10D11" },
  { initials: "MSC" , name: "MSC"     , color: "#F5BA07" },
  { initials: "ONE" , name: "ONE"     , color: "#A80F89" }
];

const modified = {
  initials: original.map(({ initials }) => initials)
};

console.log(modified);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating an Object like

```js
const newObj = {
  initiales: "HLC",
  initiales: "HMM",
  initiales: "MSC",
  initiales: "ONE",
}
```

Is equivalent to

```js
const newObj = {}
newObj.initiales = "HLC" 
newObj.initiales = "HMM" 
newObj.initiales = "MSC" 
newObj.initiales = "ONE"
```

at the end you've got:

```
const newObj = { initiales: "ONE" }
```

only