# Convert Array to object with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the given array

```
arr = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];
```

into this object:

```
result = {
'key': 'abc',
'key': 'def',
'key': 'hij'
}
```

----EDIT----

I want this structure because there is no way around other than this to pass this as queryParams in my project

Comment: That’s not possible. 1 property per name

Comment: why would you do that? what are you trying to do?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444257/creating-a-new-object-with-same-keys-and-values/66444363#66444363

Comment: object keys must be unique, I mean... did you think of how do you even access the values if you have duplicated keys?

Comment: @Georgemff I want to pass this into queryParams in URL

Comment: @ParthDeveloper if you think that "there is no way around other than this", that means you must be wrong.

Comment: @ParthDeveloper you can pass array into query params and you will get exactly what you want (key=abc&key=def&key=hij). you don't need (and you cant) to create object with same keys

Answer (score 4):

You can't create an object with duplicate keys, but you can create an array of individual objects:

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];

const result = arr.map(str => Object.create({key: str}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The output is in Array, I want output in Object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have duplicated keys for object.
But you can have array as value of an object key:

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];
const obj = {};
obj.key = arr;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// output: {"key":["abc","def","hij"]}
```

Comment: This is wrong output, I want like this: 
```{
'key': 'abc',
'key': 'def',
'key': 'hij'
}
```

Comment: you can't do that, object doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

To conveniently work with query parameters, use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Don't try to give an object multiple values for one key; that's impossible.

```js
let arr = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];
const params = new URLSearchParams;
for (const x of arr) params.append('key', x);
console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: I believe this answers the question. An excerpt from the question: ***I want this structure because there is no way around other than this to pass this as queryParams in my project***

Answer (score 1):

You are asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/614930)

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.
>
> That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

An object with duplicate keys is impossible in JavaScript.

You can use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) builtin to achieve your actual desired result:

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];
const key = "key";

const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
for (const val of arr) {
  urlSearchParams.append(key, val);
}


console.log(urlSearchParams.toString());
console.log([...urlSearchParams.entries()]);
```