# Can't save temp result inside recursion function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that receives an object with two branches of nested objects, and at the output returns one object with two properties that contain an array with all the specified values of the input object.

```js
const obj = 
  { main: 
    { value: { value: 'main value'}
    , anotherValue : 'some another value'
    }
  , offhand: 
    { value: 
      { value: 'offhand value'
      , anotherValue: 'again recursion'
      }
    }
  }

function devider(object) {
  if (typeof object == 'string') {
    return object;
  }
  if (typeof object == 'object') {
    let data = {
      fromMainHand: [],
      fromOffHand: []
    };

    for (const key in object) {
      const value = object[key];
      if (typeof value == 'string') {
        data.fromMainHand.push(devider(value));
        data.fromOffHand.push(devider(value));
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
}

console.log(devider(obj)); // {fromMainHand: Array(0), fromOffHand: Array(0)}
```

Must be:

```
{ fromMainHand : ['main value', 'some another value']
, fromOffHand  : ['offhand value', 'again recursion']
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What does "again" refer to in your title? Better have the title be the concise version of your question...

Comment: Note that your input does not have the value "offhand value": it is immediately made obsolete by the next value for the **same** property.

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444257/creating-a-new-object-with-same-keys-and-values/66444363#66444363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- <strike>Your sample input has an object literal with twice the same property. As a consequence, your input does not have the value "offhand value".</strike>> (You corrected this later in the question).
- Your `devider` function returns an object with `fromMainHand` and `fromOffHand` properties, and so when you make a recursive call, with `.push(devider(value))`, you're adding an *object* to the array, not a string value or multiple string values. The object with the two properties should only be created once.
- If the input would have numbers, booleans, or any other primitive value that is not a string, those values are ignored.

I would split this problem into two parts:

1. Create a function that retrieves all nested primitive values from an object.
2. Create another function that takes an object and translates all its values with the above described function.

The first function is a good candidate for a *generator* function. So then it looks like this:

```js
function* allValues(obj) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) { // It's a primitive value
        return yield obj;
    }
    for (const child of Object.values(obj)) {
        yield* allValues(child);
    }
}

function convert(obj) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) =>
        [key, [...allValues(val)]]
    ));
}

// Example run
const obj = {
    main: {
        value: {
            value: 'main value'
        },
        anotherValue: 'some another value'
    },
    offhand: {
        value: {
            value: 'offhand value',
            anotherValue: 'again recursion'
        }
    }
};

const result = convert(obj);
console.log(result);
```

In comments you write there should be one recursive function, which can be done in many ways. For instance, you could return the flattened arrays for each property of the given object, returning that new object, and after a recursive you could flatten that object completely to an array:

```js
function convert(obj) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) { // It's a primitive value
        return [obj];
    }
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) =>
        [key, Object.values(convert(val)).flat()]
    ));
}

// Example run
const obj = {
    main: {
        value: {
            value: 'main value'
        },
        anotherValue: 'some another value'
    },
    offhand: {
        value: {
            value: 'offhand value',
            anotherValue: 'again recursion'
        }
    }
};

const result = convert(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the shortcomings in the problem statement. fixed object literal.
the problem, unfortunately, must be solved with only one recursive function.

Comment: Added a variant to my answer which only has one recursive function (no generator). Hope it is what you need.

Comment: amazing! Thanks, the second option is what I need. I wish I was as good at working with recursive functions as you are

Answer (score 1):

When creating recursive code, I find a functional appoach is often the simplist way of approaching the task. This is split into the `flattenValues()` function for the nested objects and a `mapObject()` function to do the first layer.

```
const flattenValues = (obj) =>
  typeof obj === 'object'
    ? Object
        .values(obj)
        .map(i => flattenValues(i))
        .flat()
    : obj
  
const mapObject = (func) => (obj) => Object
  .entries(obj)
  .map(([key, value]) => [key, func(value)])
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {}) 
  
const devider = mapObject(flattenValues)

console.log(devider(obj))
```

A simpler solution can be achived via using the functional library [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com). I find this code a bit cleaner and unlike native JS, the `map()` function in Ramda supports objects.

You can have a play with this version the [Ramda codepen](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20main%3A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%27main%20value%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20anotherValue%20%3A%20%27some%20another%20value%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20offhand%3A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%27offhand%20value%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20anotherValue%3A%20%27again%20recursion%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20flattenValues%20%3D%20ifElse%28%0A%20%20is%28Object%29%2C%0A%20%20pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20%20%20map%28a%20%3D%3E%20flattenValues%28a%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20flatten%0A%20%20%29%2C%0A%20%20identity%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20devider%20%3D%20map%28flattenValues%29%0A%0Adevider%28obj%29%0A).

```js
import { flatten, identity, ifElse, is, map, pipe, values } from 'ramda'

const flattenValues = ifElse(
  is(Object),
  pipe(
    values,
    map(i => flattenValues(i)),
    flatten
  ),
  identity
)

const devider = map(flattenValues)

console.log(devider(obj))
```

In functional programming `identity` is just `(x) => x`, we have to pass an else function to `ifElse()` and this just tells it to do nothing.

In both cases I had to tidy up the input data a little, as one object had duplicate keys.

```js
const obj = {
  main: { 
    value: { 
      value: 'main value'
    },
    anotherValue : 'some another value'
  },
  offhand: { 
    value: {
      value: 'offhand value',
      anotherValue: 'again recursion'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but using third-party libraries by condition is not advisable in this task

Comment: I added a native version of the code

Answer (score 1):

Without additional context about the structure of the object and the specific keys involved, there's a risk of misinterpreting the data and pushing values to the wrong arrays. More information about the expected structure and keys would help ensure accurate categorization.

```js
const obj = {
    main: {
        value: { value: 'main value' },
        anotherValue: 'some another value'
    },
    offhand: {
        value: {
            value: 'offhand value',
            anotherValue: 'again recursion'
        }
    }
};

const data = {
    fromMainHand: [],
    fromOffHand: []
};

function devider(obj, currentKey = null) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key];
        const currentKey_ = currentKey ? `${currentKey}.${key}` : key;

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            devider(value, currentKey_);
        } else {
            if (currentKey_.startsWith('main')) {
                data.fromMainHand.push(value);
            } else if (currentKey_.startsWith('offhand')) {
                data.fromOffHand.push(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

devider(obj);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I completely agree with the comment about the risk of data distortion. however, this problem needs to be solved using a single recursive function

Comment: @DorfStil, I count a single recursive function here. Not sure what else you mean with that second part of your comment?

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest breaking the problem down into two parts. One function to flatten `values` -

```js
function *values(t)
{ if (t && typeof t == "object")
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield *values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

const obj = [1, {a: 2}, {b: [3, {d: [4] }]}]

console.log(Array.from(values(obj)))
```

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

And a second function `map` that behaves like [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) except it works on arrays *and* objects -

```js
function map(t, f)
{ if (t && typeof t == "object")
    return Array.isArray(t)
      ? t.map(f)
      : Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(t).map(k => [k, f(t[k], k, t)]))
  else
    return f(t)
}

console.log
  ( map
      ( { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
      , x => x * 100
      )
  )
```

```json
{
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300
}
```

Combining the `values` and `map` -

```js
function *values(t)
{ if (t && typeof t == "object")
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield *values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

function map(t, f)
{ if (t && typeof t == "object")
    return Array.isArray(t)
      ? t.map(f)
      : Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(t).map(k => [k, f(t[k], k, t)]))
  else
    return f(t)
}

const obj = 
  { main: 
    { value: { value: 'main value'}
    , anotherValue : 'some another value'
    }
  , offhand: 
    { value: 
      { value: 'offhand value'
      , anotherValue: 'again recursion'
      }
    }
  }

console.log
  ( map
      ( obj
      , x => Array.from(values(x))
      )
  )
```

```json
{
  "main": [
    "main value",
    "some another value"
  ],
  "offhand": [
    "offhand value",
    "again recursion"
  ]
}
```

---

I'm adding this section to show you that the `map` function above can be applied recursively -

```js
function map(t, f)
{ if (t && typeof t == "object")
    return Array.isArray(t)
      ? t.map(f)
      : Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(t).map(k => [k, f(t[k], k, t)]))
  else
    return f(t)
}

const obj = [1, {a: 2}, {b: [3, {d: [4] }]}]

console.log
  ( map
    ( obj
    , function recur(x)
      { return x && typeof x == "object"
          ? map(x, recur)
          : x * 100
      }
    )
  )
```